# socket connection without server using internet

Tags: android, sockets

I'm going to set a simple socket connection between two android devices using internet.
There are two devices and two android app's , one of them is client app and another is server app.
When the apps run on a device it's all OK, but when the apps run on two devices the client application doesn't connect to server application.

**Client app:**

```
btnSend.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        String msg = etMessage.getText().toString();
        AsyncTask.execute(() -> {
            try {
                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("100.66.20.245");
                int port = 1020;
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(
                        msg.getBytes(), msg.length(), ip, port
                );
                socket.send(packet);
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Message sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        });
});
```

**Server app:**

```
Runnable runnable = () -> {
        try {
            int port = 1020;
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,1024);
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Waiting for client",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
            socket.receive(packet);
            String msg = new String(packet.getData(),0,packet.getLength());
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Client msg : " + msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w(TAG, e.toString());
        }
};
new Thread(runnable).start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The best solution was the port forwarding with a router.**
**When you are using a router you can set an ip address to forwarding ports to that ip address.**
However if you have a better solution, please post a comment **:)**

Answer (score 1):

Are both devices connected to a network? And is the IP address of client application equal to the IP address of the server?

Comment: No , the devices are not connect to a network and the ip address of client is not equal to the server

Comment: How then do you expect a socket to connect?

Comment: I want to connect client using public ip address of server. the server device is connect to router but the client may be connect to anything

Comment: Then the client should use the public ip of the router. And on the router you should forward the used port to the local ip of your server device.

Comment: `the client may be connect to anything ` ??? Please be clear. Do you mean the client device uses a mobile connection? A sim card. Not wifi?

Comment: Yes , the client uses a mobile connection but the server is connect to a router ... do you think can i use port forwarding ??  @greenapps

Comment: You can not connect the client and server in two different networks.
Both the client and server must be in a network.

Comment: You have to use port forwarding in your setup.

Comment: Then what can i to do? i need to doing it ... The server is connect to a router that has a static ip address but the client uses mobile connection ... There is no any way ?? help me please @AbolhassanPirayeh

Comment: In this case, there will be no way to connect the server and the client without internet.
Please connect the client and server to a shared network.

Comment: If i connect the both devices to a shared network , what should i do in next step ? @AbolhassanPirayeh

Comment: No next step. Its ok that the client uses a mobile connection. But you should forward the used port in your router. And what A.P. is telling is nonsense.

Comment: The router needs an Internet connection (and preferably a static domain that resolves to its public IP. Static or dynamic is fine - there are dyndns services to handle the latter). The router then needs to open a public port that forwards traffic to the private LAN IP+port that the server listens on. When the client device is connected to mobile or an outside WiFi, it can connect to the router's public IP/domain+port and be forwarded to the server. When the client device is connected to the router's own WiFi, it can connect to the server's IP+port directly

Comment: The both must be connect to a router ??? in my scenario the client is connect to mobile connection and the server is connect to a router , can i connect the client to server ??? is it possible ?? @RemyLebeau

Comment: @AlirezaRazavi mobile is fine, as long as the router is accessible to the public internet and had port forwarding configured